# Why is my $q deferred not resolving in Angular unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm struggling to get my *first* Angular unit test to work. I'm pretty new to a lot of the concepts, but since I've already had to jump numerous hurdles to get this far, I'm posting the code. I've seen similar questions but none that helped me solve this one.

Here's a controller:

```
.controller('ThumbsCtrl', 
    ['$scope', 'backend', function($scope, backend) {
        backend.getImages()
            .then(function(images) {
                console.log("promise.then() called with "+images);
                $scope.images = images;
            }, function(err) {
               console.log(err);
            });
       }]
)
```

Here's a test:

```
describe('ThumbsCtrl', function() {
    var controller, rootScope;
    beforeEach(module('myApp.controllers'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        controller = $controller;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
    }));

    it('should contain images', inject(function($q) {
        var scope = rootScope.$new();
        var backend = {
            getImages: function() { 
                console.log("calling mock getImages()");
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve('shite');
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
        var ctrl = controller('ThumbsCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            backend: backend
        });

        expect(scope.images).toContain('shite');
    }));
});
```

The test fails because $scope.images is never set.

Putting aside comments about the sanity of having my controller's constructor call an async method (the actual backend.getImages() also returns a promise), can anyone tell me why neither the success or failure methods in the .then() call are ever called? My understanding is that by calling deferred.resolve() as I am, the unit test really should have no async code. But clearly I'm wrong... Right?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I got it to work by adding:

```
scope.$digest();
```

Before the final expect(). I'll chalk this up to still being a bit confused by $q deferreds. I was coming from using the Parse.com JS SDK, whose Promises are synchronous when they've already had resolve() called. I guess $q deferreds remain async even when resolved as above?

As a side note, the assertion that Angular supports and documents well how to unit test is not that truthy. I'm cross-referencing the AngularJS docs, an *excellent* book (Mastering Web Dev with AngularJS), and sample code from both, and I find it rather salient that a week into reading all these sources, I'm having trouble writing a simple unit test. The number of concepts to learn is LARGE, and I had also not used Jasmine before (have used QUnit). I'm trying to defer using Karma so I can take this one step at a time, but jeez -- if I didn't care a LOT about unit testing, I would have skipped it by now to write my stupid app.

Answer (score 2):

If it helps I have been having the same issues as you. I now have a standard afterEach I put after all my promise requests.

```
afterEach(function() {
    scope.$digest();
    mockBackend.flush();
    mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();

});
```

This ensures that there are no outstanding $http requests and that everything has been test properly.

And I agree its quite a hassle getting a lot of these unit tests up and running, ESPECIALLY testing directives.

Comment: Good tip @mylescc . I wonder if you or anyone would comment, is AngularJS *really* as test-friendly as it claims? I chose it largely because of DI (and because its the hottness I suppose, but it seemed that way), but in practice so far, it is NOT making me feel productive. I seriously don't like tests so cumbersome that they steer me away from refactoring code as well. I start to wonder, is this a great research project from which one can learn a lot, but not all that useful for many types of web apps?...

Comment: Actually, how would calling $digest *after* my test allow the test to pass?